# Error en EntityFramework MVC .net al meter un Card de boostrap dentro de un @foreach

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, vs

Para un trabajo practico de la carrera, tenemos que hacer una página web donde en un apartado, hay que mostrar ciertos datos, y se me ocurrió que quedaría más lindo si la info se mostrase en forma de Cards, y recurrí a Bootstrap.
El tema es que me da error en los div!! No tengo idea como solucionarlo, ¿Capaz lo que quiero hacer no está permitido?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Intenté sacando los divs, pero claramente son de tipo "Card" y es necesario que estén para que los llame desde boostrap

Comment: El error te dice que el elemento 'div' no se esta cerrando correctamente, revisa tu estructura, primero haciendo los div corrrespondientes para tu card y despues metiendo el contenido dentro de esos bloques.

Comment: Es `<br>` o `<br />`, tambien tienes un `</div>` de sobra al final